# DateTime conversion regardless of culture

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a text string that needs to become a `DateTime` object:

```
Feb 10, 2012 at 16:33.29
```

This text does not change, but the software will run on many different devices with different `DateTime` formats.

How can I set a custom `DateTime` parser so that regardless of culture I will get a fully populated `DateTime`object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ParseExact` with a custom format string and the invariant culture:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(theString, "MMM d', 'yyyy' at 'HH':'mm'.'ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

parse with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture?

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a custom format to match your example:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "Feb 10, 2012 at 16:33.29", 
    "MMM d, yyyy 'at' HH:mm.ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing has got nothing to do with the other.

`DateTime.Parse(value, formatstr)` returns a DateTime.

The DateTime does not have a format, unless you want to talk about how it's represented in memory. When you convert it to a string, you generally do it with an implicit or explicit format, once you have it is no longer a datetime...